# How to write this javascript in php or run it in php tag

Tags: javascript, php

I have created this javascript to block vpn on my website.
I would like to run this code in php or make it run inside a php tag because it is to easy to bypass this code with plugins that block javascript.
I have try to write it inside a php tag but seems not working.
Thank you so much for your help, I'm not a PHP expert so it is hard for me to find the solution.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function getIP(json) {

    var rightnow = new Date();
    var backthen = new Date(2017,07,31);
    if (rightnow<backthen)
    {

    var r = (json.ip);  
    var s = (json.org);
    var t = (json.country);
    s = / (.+)/.exec(s)[1];//hostname


    //------- ISP | FAI ---------//
    var bannedhostname=[


    "DigitalOcean, LLC",
    "Digital Ocean, Inc." , 

    ]

    //------- IP FOR TESTING THE SCRIPT ---------//
    var bannedip=[

    "0.0.0.0","45.32.149.219","138.197.142.88","159.203.21.83","138.197.142.88","104.131.124.76", 

    ]

    var handleip=bannedip.join("|");
    var handlehostname=bannedhostname.join("|");
    handleip=new RegExp(handleip, "i");
    handlehostname=new RegExp(handlehostname, "i");

    if (r.search(handleip)!=-1)
    { 


    }
    else if (s.search(handlehostname)!=-1)
    { 
        alert("Your ISP : " + json.org + " seems to be a VPN or CLOUD HOSTING, deactivate it and check again");

    }
    }
    else
    {
    alert("The VPN BLOCKER script used on this website is out of date, visit www.facebook.com/VPN-Blocker-1416592971752805 and download the update");
    }


}
  </script>

 <script type="application/javascript" 
          src="http://ipinfo.io/?callback=getIP">
  </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean _"run in php tag"_? Do you mean convert to php?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for helping with **specific** problems, not for converting code from language to language.

Comment: Not necessary to convert, but make it run inside a PHP tag

Comment: it cannot run inside a php tag, it's javascript

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp learn php

Comment: I was thinking that I can write it inside <?php     ?>

Comment: @vinscarter That's like thinking you can take a goldfish out of the water and put it in space and it should still work.

Comment: @George possibly a bit harsh, even if correct :)

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, You can't do this because in the end on browser level it will be parsed as JS and if any plugin disable JS or browser JS is disabled than JS will not work on the browser.

Comment: Oh alright, thank for the answer, so it realy need to be write entire in PHP.

Comment: Yeah! correct, whatever logic you are having, that should be written in PHP itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply assign all the Js in a php variable and each that variable whenever you want to execute this js code.